# Can I download update files from server and replace files in supporting folder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am doing iPhone app dev. Usually, I put image(photo) files and some other configuration files in to supporting folder.

1. Can I update those files in supporting folder from server? If can, how to do it?
2. If not, can I pre-store the files which are need to upload into Document Folder and download newer files in document folder to replace older files?

Comment: you can store first the images in document directory and pass the date in to the web services and get update it and download the image in the document directory.  you are trying this ???

Comment: Yes, if it is not possible to update files in supporting files folder(named in XCODE) directly. I prefer to find a way to download update files (maybe image files, maybe html files or text files) from server and replace them which I put in supporting files folder (can find this folder in Xcode navigator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we had the same problem in our current app. our final approach is this:

1) the assets we want to deliver with the app are stored inside a folder under `Resources`.
[image: screenshot xcode]

2) Plus there is an XML file telling us, which asset belongs where and how old it is (timestamp).
[image: xml snippet]

3) When the app starts for the first time, we copy all files (except the xml) from `Rescources` to the app's `Cache` folder:

```
// get the app's cache folder

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
_cachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
_assetDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/assets", _cachesDirectory];

// copy everything

_fmngr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

- (void) copyAllFilesFromInitialFolder:(NSString*)path
{
    NSArray *files = [_fmngr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
    for (NSString *file in files) 
    {
        if ([file isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.xml", kDefaultXMLFileName]])
        {
            continue;
        }

        NSString *fpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", path, file];
        BOOL isDir;  
        if ([_fmngr fileExistsAtPath:fpath isDirectory:&isDir])
        {
            if (isDir)
            {
                [self copyAllFilesFromInitialFolder:fpath];
            }
            else
            {
                NSString *relPath = [fpath substringFromIndex:[_initialLangDeviceContentPath length]+1];
                NSString *fileName = [self convertFilePathToName:relPath];
                NSString *tpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", _assetDirectory, fileName];

                NSError *error;
                BOOL success = [_fmngr copyItemAtPath:fpath toPath:tpath error:&error];
                if (!success || error) 
                {
                    NSLog(@"INFO: copy %@ to CACHES failed ... file may already be there.", file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4) At the next start of the application, we check online if there are newer files on our update server. The XML from step 2) also resides on the server and has to be updated when JPGs/PNGs/... are updated/replaced on the server.
If nothing changed our PHP script returns a 304 "not modfied" - otherwise it'll output an updated version of the XML.

the PHP script looks something like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->load($filename);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$assets = $xpath->query('//asset');
if ($assets->length > 0)
{
    foreach ($assets as $asset) 
    {
        $assetPath = $asset->getAttribute('path');
        if (file_exists($assetPath)) 
        {
            $atime = filemtime($assetPath);
            $asset->setAttribute('modified', $atime);
        }
        else
        {
            // file not found - link broken
            $asset->setAttribute('modified', '0');
        }
    }
}

$output = $doc->saveXML();
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $output;
```

The app downloads and parses the generated XML, comparing all `modified` values.
When there is an asset with a newer modified timestamp it is deleted locally and redownloaded. only after this check is completed the app starts - and you got the new assets on the device.

Hope this helps. We had some problems with the `last modified` attribute of the files we deliver with the app. When including the files into the app bundle and copying them at runtime, the files `last modified` is always the time of the first start of the app. sometimes you already updated some files on the server - but because the app thinks the files on the device are newer (because they were copied just now) they are not re-dowloaded from the server :(
so you can't work with the real file's attributes but have to include the actual file-date inside the XML file.

Comment: Many thanks for your details!!! Really helped!!! For the issue you mentioned above, why not just set a node like version=1.0 and list all files which are up to date needed in it, also list all obsolete files. Then you can compare the version node inside xml each time to see if need to up files to date. Of course only download all files list in xml and delete files list in xml. That can avoid the problem you said. What do you say?

Comment: the problem was, that the designers wanted to be able to update the assets by themselves (just upload a bunch of files via FTP) and the `last modified` timestamp is something we could get via script - the `version` parameter would have to be set by hand. so we went with the timestamp instead.

Comment: hm... I'll work on it in the next few days, anything I got will update you~ @pkyeck

Comment: Maybe you can try MD5, the XML contains file name and file byte stream MD5, and every time you can just compare file name and its MD5, if MD5 is different, up it to date.

Comment: we hab a couple of hundred files and no CMS - just the uploaded files, a manually created XML and the PHP script. in this scenario, doing the MD5() every time someone asked for the script was way too slow (around 30sec). so i stuck with the timestamps.

Comment: you can try collect file attribute such as modify date. Store in a NSArray, after finished copy, change file attribute like `   NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

   NSLog(@"%@", [[fm attributesOfItemAtPath:@"input.txt" error:NULL] fileModificationDate]);
   [fm setAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSDate date] forKey:NSFileModificationDate]
     ofItemAtPath:@"input.txt" error:NULL];`  The code is run on OS X, but you can try on iOS

Comment: Is it possible to use DropBox type service instead? and have the code track "Last Modified" without the need for the service side XML.

Comment: public folder in dropbox should be possible (+ include XML in app with all links). but then adding new assets would be a problem and you'd have to compare every file with the current one on the server (many calls to the server instead of one for the XML)